# Conditional rendering with OR operator

Tags: android, react-native, conditional-rendering

I have the following code;

```
       {
          this.state.isWPAEnterpriseInstalled && !this.state.passpoint && !this.state.expanded || this.state.isWPAEnterpriseInstalled && !this.state.expanded && this.state.isEnterprise && <TouchableOpacity style={!this.state.expanded ? [styles.button, { backgroundColor: this.state.primary_color }] : [styles.expandedButton, { backgroundColor: this.state.primary_color }]}
            activeOpacity={0} onPress={this.removeConfigEnterprise}>
            <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={styles.button_text}>Remove WPA </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }
```

The problem I am having is with the condition render line;

```
this.state.isWPAEnterpriseInstalled && !this.state.passpoint && !this.state.expanded || this.state.isWPAEnterpriseInstalled && !this.state.expanded && this.state.isEnterprise &&
```

It's like it only recognises one of these condition between the OR operator i.e. whichever is placed first. Is it possible that the OR (||) operator is not available in React with conditional rendering?

If so, how can I achieve the below? e.g. render based on 2 OR condition.

```
IF ABC AND GH AND ER OR DEF AND FGH AND TYU then display button
```

**EDIT**

Resolved.  Above code worked but had a mismatch in one of states set where I expected a different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that the OR (||) operator is not available in React with conditional rendering?

No, JSX should accept any JavaScript expression.

> If so, how can I achieve the below? e.g. render based on 2 OR condition.

`IF ABC AND GH AND ER OR DEF AND FGH AND TYU then display button`

The way `&&` shorthand works for conditional rendering is explained here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

It works because `true && VALUE` always returns `VALUE` which in this case is the element to be rendered.

But when we add an OR operator in between, it returns the boolean value instead of the element.

To fix this, you will need to wrap the entire statement in parenthesis.

And you may want to consider using inline if-else statement instead since when using this technique with non boolean values(ex - strings) react-native [can crash](https://medium.com/dailyjs/conditional-rendering-in-react-native-may-crash-your-app-83d152fd4a04) due to text being rendered outside of `Text` elements.

Comment: Curious here, would you mind explaining why react-native can crash when using conditional rendering?

Comment: @IanVasco if one of values in the expression returns a string, react-native will try to render it as a string and cause a crash because strings can only be rendered in Text elements. You can read a bit more about it here: https://medium.com/dailyjs/conditional-rendering-in-react-native-may-crash-your-app-83d152fd4a04

Comment: Alright, then I'd suggest putting the advice as evaluating the boolean value for the desired variable, instead of mentioning "some cases" which is way broader :)

Comment: That's a valid point. I'll edit the answer to include that.

Comment: This is brilliant - thanks for that explanation.  Make perfect sense and yet I had no idea!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question properly so tell me if I'm wrong, but I think you're missing parenthesis there.
I think you're trying to render `this.state.isWPAEnterpriseInstalled`

Maybe you meant to write the following :

```
(this.state.isWPAEnterpriseInstalled && !this.state.passpoint && !this.state.expanded) || (this.state.isWPAEnterpriseInstalled && !this.state.expanded && this.state.isEnterprise) && <TouchableOpacity>...
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks for that - no, it was my own doing.  2 conditions met were both true - I expected one of them to be false. Fixed now, I just overlooked some previous code before this.

Comment: Your answer actually solved another similar scenario I ran into just now though :) Thanks for that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help then :)